# Folder TestResults of Specflow Execution Report is Wrong

Tags: visual-studio, specflow, specrun

When I run my tests with SpecFlow, my TestResults folder become:
C:\PROJETOS\CapitalElevado\TestResults\C\PROJETOS\CapitalElevado\TestResults

In other words, my "C" directory is being seen like a folder and then the full address repeats.

I don´t know how to solve that.

My Sample.runsettings contains:

```
<RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework40</TargetFrameworkVersion>
 </RunConfiguration>
```

I´m using SpecFlow / SpecRun 1.7.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in SpecFlow+Runner (aka SpecRun) 1.7.*. 
The issue for it is here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1191

Is will be fixed with the next version.

There is a workaround for this.
Define the report in the Report section of the srProfile (http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/Report). This will generate the report at the correct location.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+.